# .htaccess mode_rewrite regex expression not matching

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying the following regex for mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule [^\s].* /product/pllist.php
```

The sample url is *www.example.com/matchthis* I want to match if there is something written after www.example.com,

In the above regex it matches, but if I give www.example.com without anything after it, it returns error rather than redirecting to www.example.com

**Edit**

I have other rewite url too it should work too

```
RewriteRule ^style\/ /style/fashion.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rewrite everything to `/product/pllist.php` then use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^style/?$ /style/fashion.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ product/pllist.php [L]
```

Your regex `^[\s].*` will not match empty string hence `http://www.domain.com/` will not be rewritten.

Comment: Ok it is working but my other rewrite given above in edit is not working when i use this

Comment: Thank you this worked ! ,Is there any security issues in this method above

Comment: No I don't think there is any security issue here.

Comment: You mean security issue is there

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match an specific URI you could use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/matchthis [NC]
RewriteRule . /product/pllist.php [L]
```